# Celebrity Numbers

Tags: pattern

Here's one that I expect to be pretty easy

---

Every celebrity has been given a number that describes them in some way. Here are some of the most popular.

These are "correct" descriptions:

> Tom Petty: 2
>   Jimmy Carter: 2
>   Adolf Hitler: 3
>   Charles Dance: 2
>   Bob Dylan: 2
>   Michael Jackson: 2

These are "incorrect" descriptors:

> Donald Trump: 4
>   Steve Harvey: 3
>   Buddy Holly: 2
>   Betty White: 3
>   William McKinley: 2

What does the number describe about these celebrities?

Comment: Hitler... a... _celebrity_...?

Comment: He is famous, after all :P

Comment: Hitler... a... ... ... *celebrity*???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number is their

> Bacon number. 
>  According to Wikipedia, this is based on the idea of six degrees of separation, which suggests that any 2 people are at most 6 acquaintances apart. The Bacon number states how 'far apart' the person is from the actor Kevin Bacon based on film roles.

Comment: Thought it would be solved quickly! I'll accept this as the answer when I can in 10 minutes. In the meantime, can you explain this for those who might not know?

Comment: Sure, will update in a moment. Incidentally I was tripped up when Google told me Hitler's Bacon number was 2, but luckily I caught the small text on the Wikipedia result which said it was 3.